# Why when I open Dialog it will disable all qml item

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, drawer

I have a custom dialog in my qt quick application,when I click a button to open the it,I will got the below error:

> QQuickItem::stackBefore: Cannot stack before 0x6d4bd6e220, which must be a sibling

After this error,All qml Items on the `main.qml` page will disable and don't work and don't interact width mouse.

**main.qml**

```
onClicked: {     
                var c= userPorfileCom.createObject(mainWindow);
                 c.open();
            }

Component{
    id:userPorfileCom
    UserProfilePage{
        id: userProfilePage
    }
}
```

**UserProfilePage.qml**

```
JooyaDialog{
id: root
IranSanseFontLoader{
    id: fl
}
onVisibleChanged: {
    if(visible)
    {
        up.getProfile();
    }
}
header: ToolBar{
    id: tbheader
    Material.primary: "white"
    Material.elevation:1
    RowLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        ToolButton{
            contentItem: Image {
                source: "/images/close.png"
                fillMode: Image.Pad
                horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter
            }
            onClicked: {
                close();
            }
        }
    }
}

signal profileHasChanged;
UserProfile{
    id: up
    name: tfName.text
    lastName: tfLastName.text
    gender: cbxGender.currentIndex==0
    email: tfEmail.text
    phoneNumber: tfMobile.text
    onProfileChanged: {
        loginManager.getUserInfo();
    }
    onMessageChanged: {
        showMessage(message);
    }
    onIsProcessingChanged: {
        console.log("progr in user info");
        bipi.visible=isProcessing;
    }
}

title: qsTr("ویرایش اطلاعات کاربری")
rootWidth:mainWindow.width
rootHeight: mainWindow.height
contentHeight:rootHeight/2

font{
    family: fl.name
    pixelSize: 18
    bold: true
}
//================================================
Flickable{
    id: flickable
    contentHeight: mainClm.implicitHeight+100
    flickableDirection: Flickable.AutoFlickIfNeeded
    clip: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    Pane{
        anchors.fill:parent

        Material.accent: Material.Pink
        ColumnLayout{
            id: mainClm
            anchors.fill: parent

            JooyaTextField{
                id: tfName
                placeholderText: "نام"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: up.name
            }
            JooyaTextField{
                id: tfLastName
                placeholderText: "نام خانوادگی"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: up.lastName
            }
            ComboBox {
                id: cbxGender
                model: ["مرد", "زن"]
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                currentIndex:
                {
                    if(up.gender)
                    {
                        return 0// "مرد"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 1//"زن"
                    }
                }
            }
            JooyaTextField{
                id: tfMobile
                placeholderText: "شماره موبایل"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: up.phoneNumber
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
            }
            JooyaTextField{
                id: tfEmail
                placeholderText: "ایمیل"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: up.email
            }
            JooyaButton{
                id: btnSave
                text: "ذخیره"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                highlighted: true
                onClicked: {
                    up.saveProfile();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{
        width: 3
    }

}
ProgressIndicator{
    id: bipi
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If two items are in the tab focus chain while not being siblings it won't work,
meaning that what is in the tab focus chain must have the same immediate parent.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#stackBefore

Comment: I don't khow how use this for solving the problem

Comment: I can't really help you further, the issue isn't with the code you provided as far as I can tell. You might need to debug to figure out what calls QQuickItem::stackBefore(const QQuickItem *sibling) and what 0x6d4bd6e220 is, in order to make them siblings.